# How do EGit versions map to Git versions

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

The Git Source Code Mirror on GitHub (https://github.com/git/git) says that the most recent version of Git is 2.7.4. I'm using EGit 3.5.2 on Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse Luna SR1), so that version number obviously doesn't correspond to a Git version. Is there any way to trace back what version of Git this version of EGit is based off of?

I checked here, but it only maps versions of EGit to versions of Eclipse...

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_is_Git.3F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, EGit does not appear to be based on a particular version of Git.  The EGit [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#How_compatible_is_EGit_with_Git.3F) has the following to say:

> ## How compatible is EGit with Git?
>
> Some, but not all configuration options/features in Git are available in EGit/JGit. Here is a summary, not yet complete describing some of these, including notable differences. **Note that the set of EGit/JGit is not based off a particular Git version.**

Practically speaking, as long as you are using the most recent version of Git, you should be OK.  This is because Git itself should be backwards-compatible with whatever version of Git was concurrent with the particular release of EGit which you are using.  But I would not recommend the other way around, e.g. using the first release of Git from many years ago with the latest EGit plugin.

Comment: Interesting, I don't recall installing Git. I thought that EGit was Git, only adapted to work in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

There is no correlation between EGit and Git versions. EGit uses [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/), a pure Java implementation of the Git VCS, to access repositories. JGit versions do not follow a specific Git versions either. Though JGit is relatively on par with Git, some things are missing, for example `git clone -- depth`. Unfortunately, a detailed comparison does not exist