# What Version of Git is used by EGit in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, gitignore, egit

You'd think this would be an easy question, but since Git is, of course, itself a "Version Control" system Google gets very confused by a query like the title of this post.

Be that as it may, I'm running Eclipse Luna and trying to understand what version of Git is being used by the Eclipse EGit plugin.

This is so that I can understand what is going on with `.gitignore` files.

It seems that the [documentation on gitignore provided at the official site](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) is not in synch with the git provider in Eclipse, particularly in regard to the handling of leading and trailing `**` notations.

I know that the version of git that ships with RHEL 6.7 (git v. 1.7.1) does not handle `**` as per the documentation, and that this was only remedied in 1.8.2, but now I'm also noticing that Eclipse doesn't seem to recognize the `**` either.

Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do EGit versions map to Git versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076840/how-do-egit-versions-map-to-git-versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse uses egit which is an eclipse team provider for jgit [1] which is a "lightweight, pure Java library implementing the Git version control system" [2]

You have to follow the egit documentation [3], not the git documentation. They can both read and write the same git repository format, and talk the git protocol, but otherwise do not have exactly the same commands. So the git documentation you're referencing may not apply.

[1 http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/)

[2 http://www.eclipse.org/egit/](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)

[3 http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide)

Comment: Thanks.  I was surprised to learn since posting this that Eclipse is shipping with EGit 3.4, which does not support the `**` syntax, whereas EGit 4.3 is available in the Eclipse marketplace and this has been supported several versions back.  That is a simple solution, and I recognize now that my whole question was somewhat misguided, since EGit has only a loose connection to any particular version of Git.

Answer (score 0):

You can always update git to the latest version and work from the command line in order to be sure what version you have.

What version of Egit (not git) do you have installed?

If you dont find you can always look under the plugin folder and in the Egit folder itself.